# C# .NET: How to choose which Network adapter to connect my Application at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, networking, wifi, lan

My Laptop is connected to a LAN and a WIFI and have a separate Network Connection,
My SQL server is in the same network as my LAN and I have a FUNCTION that PING'S the SQL Server First Before running the Query, Now the problem is every time i run my Dekstop App its Choosing the WIFI Connection to PING the server instead of the LAN.
I can get a list of my Network Adapters and determine which is LAN or WIFI but how do i tell my application which one to use?

```
NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
{
    if (adapter.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
    {
        if (adapter.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("No Connection to SQL Server");
        }
        else
        {         
          GetPING();  //PING SERVER FUNCTION IF TRUE
          MessageBox.Show("Connected to SQL, Run App Now.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You don't normally have to do anything in a client application to tell it which adapter to use. I.e. if the server name resolves to a LAN address then the networking stack will use the LAN adapter.

Comment: Sorry about the Confusion forgot to add my function that PINGS the Server. Edited my Question.

Comment: The route is determined by the IP address and Mask.  Windows looks at all the active connections and and takes the route with the most restricted mask.  So it will take 255.255.255.0 before 255.255.0.0.  Use cmd.exe > IPCONFIG /all to see the IP address of the adapters and masks.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain all IP addresses that has set on a network interface by access `NetworkInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses` property. After that, what you need to do will depend on how did you implement your PING fuction.

1. If you just execute PING.exe, there's -S option could let you to spicify source address that you want to use to ping.
2. If you use a `Socket` to send out icmp echo message, you need to call `Socket.Bind` method to specify local endpoint.